# htaccess deny access to URIs via regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to deny access to all my posts/pages via their database id address e.g. `/?p=1` , `/?p=2` , ... etc

I am looking at doing this using .htaccess and would guess it would be best done with a RewriteCond rule. I have tried this but it doesn't appear to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?p=*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

As per OP's comments to match `p` or `page` with `=` digits try following then.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p|page)=[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: That works! thanks. Sorry also I wanted to include a ban on the use of ^page_id=[0-9]  as well. How could I incorporate that in to the code?

Comment: @Matt, Please try my 2nd edited rules once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Had to add "_id" to the end of "^page" but yes it works, brilliant thanks. Upvoted and accepted

Comment: @Matt, ok(looks like your comments updated), so your condition has become like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p|page)=[0-9]+_id$ [NC]`? If yes then please confirm me I will edit my answer then, cheers.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 the condition I settled with is `RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p|page_id)=[0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]`

Comment: @Matt, oh ok, got it, thanks for letting know, cheers.